# When writing a save file, empty blank spaces before the data are placed, and I think they are interfering with data

Tags: c#

Sorry to bother you all once more, your previous feedback worked greatly. I previously made a saving system with your help that writes an int named Money in a .txt file, and I am currently trying to make it load your money so you can start again where you left off. When the save file is written, it seems to write empty lines before the amount of money based on the amount of money. For example if the amount of money you had when you saved was 8 you would have 7 empty spaces before the 8, but if it were 4 it would have 3. I'm not sure if it is related, but when you press load, your money goes to 0 no matter how much money you currently have. I have also tried deleting the spaces manually in the .txt file so the first line is 8 without any spaces before, but that didn't work either. My current code for saving is:

```
    private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String filename = NameBox.Text;
        if (filename == "")
        {
            filename = "New Save";
        }
        filename += ".txt";
        String[] Money = new String[MainForm.Money];
        Money[MainForm.Money - 1] = MainForm.Money.ToString();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, Money);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

And my current code for loading is:

```
    private void LoadBtn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadMoney();
    }
    public void LoadMoney()
    {
        String money = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename).ToString();
        String line;
        line = money.ToString();
        if (int.TryParse(line, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out MainForm.Money))
        {
            Money = int.Parse(line);
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much for coping with my inexperience/ignorance in advance!

Comment: Why is `Money` an array? Thats the reason you are writing out so many lines.

Comment: The way I learned to make save files involved an array, so I'm not familiar with how to make a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with you writing lots of lines to the file comes from how you are saving the file. This makes an array equal to how much money you have `String[] Money = new String[MainForm.Money];` So if MainForm.Money is equal to 10, then that's how big your array is. Next, `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines()` Writes each line of the array out, so if you array has 9 blank values and 1 value with the actual money, it will write out 9 blank lines and then 1 line with the value you want.

To fix this, change your method to this.

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String filename = NameBox.Text;
    if (filename == "")
    {
        filename = "New Save";
    }
    filename += ".txt";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, MainForm.Money.ToString());
    Application.Exit();
}
```

That will only write out one line, and it will the value of `MainForm.Money`.

I'm sure if you loading as it stands will work, but changing it like this will work for sure.

```
public void LoadMoney()
{
    String money = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename).Trim(); //trim removes all whitespace at the beginning and the end. May not be needed, but I personally do it just in case.
    if (int.TryParse(line, out MainForm.Money))
    {
        //MainForm.Money will already be set to the correct value here. You probably only need to check if it doesnt parse, and then handle that case.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I'll make sure to use WriteAllText and ReadAllText when I am saving only one line next time!